# React Native Using Expo not showing Icon correctly [ (X) and ? ]

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome, expo, ionicons

I have a problem of displaying the icon with my App.
Whatever Icon I import, eg: From React native base, @expo/vector-icons, react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons ... etc.

It will only show (X) or ?

I tried out many method, including react-native link, using the default import icon from React-Native. It all doesn't work.

**Reference:**

1) https://ionicons.com/cheatsheet.html

2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ionicons

I will attach my code and screenshot here, hope it help to solve my problem. Thank you.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons'


        <ListItem style={styles.listitem_home} onPress={this.navigateToScreen('ExampleSendDataScreen')}>
          <Thumbnail square size={80} source={require('../../assets/images/message.png')}  style={{marginRight: 10}}/>
          <Body>
            <Text>{Strings.ST17}</Text>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} note style={styles.note_home}>{Strings.ST17}</Text>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Icon name="menu" style={styles.icon_home} />                
          </Right>
        </ListItem>
```

Icon Styles

```
icon_home:{

fontSize: 20,
color: 'black'
},
```

The only icon show in my app currently is Navigator Back Button.
[image]

[image]

**Edit 1: Installed @expo/vector-icons 9.0.0**
[image]
[image]

**Edit 2: Updated to Expo v32**

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
"@types/expo__vector-icons": "^6.2.3",
"antd-mobile": "^2.2.6",
"babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
"es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"firebase": "^5.8.1",
"haversine": "^1.1.0",
"moment": "^2.23.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
"native-base": "^2.8.1",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"re-base": "^4.0.0",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-moment": "^0.8.4",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-audio": "^4.3.0",
"react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
"react-native-button": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
"react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.1.6",
"react-native-fontawesome": "^6.0.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
"react-native-gifted-messenger": "^0.1.4",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
"react-native-ionicons": "^4.4.6",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.4",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3",
"react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
"react-native-navbar": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
"react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-timeago": "^0.4.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.0.7",
"react-navigation-header-buttons": "^2.1.1",
"react-simple-line-icons": "^1.0.8",
"scheduler": "^0.11.3",
"tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"  },
```

**App.json**

```
"expo": {
"name": "FirstTry",
"description": "This project is really great.",
"slug": "firsttry",
"privacy": "public",
"sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
"platforms": ["ios", "android"],
"version": "2.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"androidStatusBarColor": "#7bcbdb",
"androidStatusBar": {
"barStyle": "light-content",
"backgroundColor": "#7bcbdb"
},
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*"
],
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.firsttry",
  "supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.firsttry",
  "versionCode": 2

}
```

**New ERROR. undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.Constant') on my ConfigApp.js**

[image]

**ConfigApp.js**

```
import Expo from 'expo';

const isStandAloneApp = Expo.Constants.appOwnership == "standalone";

const ConfigApp = {

// backend url
URL: "YOUR_BACKEND_URL",

// banner admob unit id
BANNER_ID: "YOUR_BANNER_ID",

// interstitial admob unit id
INTERSTITIAL_ID: "YOUR_INTERSTITIAL_ID",

// testdevice id, DON'T CHANGE IT
TESTDEVICE_ID : isStandAloneApp?"EMULATOR" : "EMULATOR"
};

export default ConfigApp;
```

**Edit 3:  Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons" from "application\navigations\Logged.js"**

```
const leftIcon = (navigation, icon) => <Ionicons
name={icon}
style={{marginLeft: 20}}
size={27}
color="white"
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
/>; 

  HomeScreen: {
screen: HomeScreen,
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  headerLeft: leftIcon(navigation, "md-menu")
})
},
```

**Edit 4: Icon still not display correctly**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can’t use `react-native-ionicons` with Expo as the installation process requires you to update **native** code. https://github.com/fanqfanh/react-native-ionicons

However Expo comes bundled with Ionicons which can be used in the following way:

Add the following import statement at the top of your component

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Then use them like this

```
<Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="green" />
```

You should also check the **correct** name to use here

https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/

this is because `vector-icons` can use different names from the original icon package that you are using.

For more information about the different icons that are in Expo see the documentation

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/

Here is a simple snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/iconicons-example
It shows the differences between icons for iOS and Android, and how to switch them based on the platform.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="green" />
        <Ionicons name="ios-menu" size={32} color="red" />
        <Ionicons name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "ios-menu" : 'md-menu'} size={32} color="blue" />
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark" size={32} color="green" />
        <Ionicons name="ios-checkmark" size={32} color="red" />
        <Ionicons name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "ios-checkmark" : 'md-checkmark'} size={32} color="blue" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

## Updates to the `package.json`

I've commented which dependencies I think you can safely get rid of from your `package.json`. These should not have been added as they either require access to native code or are already included in `Expo`.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0", // already included in expo
  "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.0",
  "@types/expo__vector-icons": "^6.2.3", // only required if you are using typescript, but I don't think you are using that
  "antd-mobile": "^2.2.6",
  "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
  "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
  "expo": "^32.0.0",
  "firebase": "^5.8.1",
  "haversine": "^1.1.0", 
  "moment": "^2.23.0",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
  "native-base": "^2.8.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
  "re-base": "^4.0.0",
  "react": "16.5.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-audio": "^4.3.0", // can't be used in Expo as it requires native code
  "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
  "react-native-button": "^2.3.0",
  "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
  "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.1.6",
  "react-native-fontawesome": "^6.0.1", // requires you to add the font yourself, also it is included in expo
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.12", // already included in expo
  "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
  "react-native-gifted-messenger": "^0.1.4",
  "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0", // can't use this in expo as it requires native code
  "react-native-ionicons": "^4.4.6", // already included in expo, 
  "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.4",
  "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.3", // can't be used in expo as it requires native code
  "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1", // already included in expo
  "react-native-navbar": "^2.1.0",
  "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
  "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
  "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9", // cannot use this in expo as it requires native code
  "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1", // cannot use this in expo as it requires native code
  "react-native-timeago": "^0.4.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0", // cannot use this in expo as it requires native code
  "react-navigation": "^3.0.7",
  "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^2.1.1",
  "react-simple-line-icons": "^1.0.8",
  "scheduler": "^0.11.3", // this is used internally by React, I don't think you require it here
  "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"  
},
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187693/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-react-native-using-expo-not-showing-icon-correctl).

Comment: I did this, and the solution from the answer below, and it still isn't working :(

Comment: I get `MaterialCommunityIcons' cannot be used as a JSX component` whenever I try to insert it as a child.

Answer (score 2):

You must use

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

instead of

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
```

to register your main component. Here is the solution in Expo https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/issues/89#issuecomment-475217923

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting the SQUARE X's due to a step required by react-native-svg-transformer. This was only a problem after I upgraded from SDK38 to SDK40.

For me, the workaround that worked was to remove the metro.config.js file that the transformer module requested I add. I'm not even sure if I was using the functionality that required this transformer anymore.. Removing it had no detrimental effect for me. It may have a detrimental effect for you, but it's worth a try to see if it fixes yours. I documented a bug here to alert the SVG Transformer team in case there's a fix required on their side.

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer/issues/128

So in summary the workaround is to remove metro.config.js (or remove the alterations made to metro.config.js if you had one before this module's changes), then "expo start -c" and try again..

Let me know if that helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the icons not rendering correctly, even if most of the things were setup right.

It had to do with the fact I used a custom metro.config.js file with this code inside.

```
transformer: {
     babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-sass-transformer'),
},
```

That would override the transformer needed for vector icons.
I ended up following this answer, and it worked:

[Configure multiple transformers/resolvers using metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656845/configure-multiple-transformers-resolvers-using-metro)