# Configure multiple transformers/resolvers using metro

Tags: javascript, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to add multiple resolvers and transformers using metro for my react native project, how do I combine them in my metro.config.js file?

Background: I want to get both a sass transformer to work as well as a svg transformer.

I've tried the configurations separately and that seems to work, but I'm confused to how I combine them so they both work at the same time. I'm assuming they need to be in the same module.exports, because when they both are in the same file I get errors for my svg's

These are the configs I'm trying to combine:

```
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-sass-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "scss", "sass"]
    }
  };
})();
```

When I try to run it with the code as above, that is two module exports in the metro.config.js, it seems that only the sass transformer works, when I try to draw an svg I get the following error:

```
Invariant violation: Element type is invalid: Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got number.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom transformer as follows:

customTransformer.js :

```
// For React Native version 0.59 or later
var upstreamTransformer = require("metro-react-native-babel-transformer");
var sassTransformer = require("react-native-sass-transformer");
var svgTransformer = require("react-native-svg-transformer");

module.exports.transform = function({ src, filename, options }) {
  if (filename.endsWith(".scss") || filename.endsWith(".sass")) {
    return sassTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  } else if (filename.endsWith(".svg")) {
    return svgTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }  else {
    return upstreamTransformer.transform({ src, filename, options });
  }
};
```

And in my metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("./customTransformer.js")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg" && ext!=="scss"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg", "scss", "sass"]
    }
  };
})();
```

No idea if this is the best way, but it seems to work

Comment: This is the only way I've found that works. I tried to use mergeConfig from the metro docs, but since it doesn't deeply merge the objects, the transformers always get overwritten by whichever config you merge in last.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem using mergeConfig from metro-config

```
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('metro-config');
/* ... */
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  const svgTransformer = {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
    },
  };

  const obfuscatingTransformer = {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
    },
    ...jsoMetroPlugin,
  };

  return mergeConfig(svgTransformer, obfuscatingTransformer);
})();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This likely won't work. See the source for mergeConfig at https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/main/packages/metro-config/src/loadConfig.js#L150 - it just picks one of the babelTransformerPaths, it doesn't actually merge them like the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('metro-config');

const config1 = {};
const config2 = {};

module.exports = mergeConfig(config1, config2);
```

It will return the merged configuration of two or more configuration objects.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This likely won't work. See the source for mergeConfig at https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/main/packages/metro-config/src/loadConfig.js#L150 - it just picks one of the babelTransformerPaths, it doesn't actually merge them like the accepted answer.